# ¿Es "aun cuando" utilizado solamente en el lenguaje culto o literario?

Tags: conjunciones

¿Es verdad que la locución **aun cuando**, si se utiliza con el mismo sentido que *aunque* o *a pesar de*, pertenece al lenguaje literario/culto?

Answer (score 3):

En principio, no.

En la entrada de aun del DRAE se menciona esta construcción:

> **[aun cuando](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4ObzbDY)**
>
> 1. loc. conjunt. conc. aunque. No renunciará a su patrimonio aun cuando tenga que luchar por él en los tribunales.
>
> <sub>*loc. conjunt. conc.* quiere decir locución conjuntiva
>   concesiva</sub>

El DRAE suele ser bastante exhaustivo en estas cuestiones y aquí no menciona que su uso sea culto. A mí, personalmente, no me lo parece en exceso. Sí es verdad que no es la frase que diría mirando un partido de fútbol con los amigotes, pero tampoco tiene una connotación demasiado exquisita.